# Intuition behind statistical approach for Hypothesis testing

Tags: intuition, hypothesis-testing

I have studied Hypothesis testing from [thinkstats2](https://greenteapress.com/thinkstats2/thinkstats2.pdf) which does simulation to estimate p value.

For e.g. In coin toss example, we run the simulation, to generate the test statistic i.e. Difference between the number of Heads and Tails. p value is the proportion of test statistics greater than observed. So intuitively:

- if $p$ is low >> not randomness, its serious >> reject Ho
- if $p$ is high >> its randomness behind your Ha >> no reason to reject Ho

So p value is the probability of randomness behind observing the test statistic

Taking the intuition to a statistics-based approach, Instead of producing observations of test statistics (e.g. in Difference in number of heads, tails) through simulation --> In the statistical approach, we should be creating the observations/distribution through knowledge of empirical distribution.

Is my understanding correct? If this is correct then any help on how we should be creating this distribution?

Ultimately we have to answer:Is it randomness behind my observation (Ha) or something serious?

Comment: The p-value of an observation is the probability that -- Assuming the hypothesis is TRUE -- you'd get a an observation at least as far out as the one you got. So if the p-value is very small, it's very unlikely you'd get such an observation if the hypothesis were true. As far as rejecting vs. accepting, that involves choosing a cut-off point which in practice is often taken to be 0.05, but there's no purely mathematical reason for that choice (vs. 0.01 or 0.08 or whatever), as far as I know.